# Is uncountable union of elements of $\sigma-$algebra still $\sigma-$algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Here I just reference the definition from Wiki:

A $\sigma-$algebra has three conditions:

1. $X$ is in $\sigma-$algebra.
2. Closed under complementation.
3. Closed under **countable union.**

My question is $\sigma-$algebra closed under **uncountable union** ?

Comment: No, take the standard Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\Bbb R$. Then every set would be measurable if that were so.

Comment: @AdamHughes I didn't mention about measurable?  by the way, can you write a detail example about you idea? Thanks

Comment: By definition elements of a $\sigma$ algebra are called the measurable sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is true then every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be Lebesgue mesurable, since
$$ S = \bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\}
$$
Moreover, if the given $\sigma$-algebra contains all singletons, it must be the whole power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Then it would be difficult to define measures on such $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=[0,1]$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all subsets $A\subset X$ such that either $A$ or its complement is countable. Then one can show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

However, $\mathcal{A}$ is not closed under uncountable unions, because for instance each set $\{x\}$ with $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, but the union $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

If a $\sigma$ algebra over a set $S$ is closed by uncountable union it contains all the elements of $\mathcal P(S)$ since they're all unions of singletons. Such $\sigma$ algebra is trivial.